# C++ plugin type export

Tags: c++, vb.net, command-line-interface, mef

Sorry for asking again but meanwhile I got my stuff running. However, my host application does not accept my Plugin (written in C++/CLI) as an IPlugin.

Code in C++/CLI Plugin.dll header:

```
#pragma once

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace SharedLibrary;
using namespace Plugin_Interface;

namespace MyCppPlugin {
    public ref class MyPlugin abstract : public Plugin_Interface::IPlugin
    {
    public:
        virtual bool CreateInstance(SharedLibrary::MemoryArbiter^%, 
                                    SharedLibrary::clsMessageQueue^%, 
                                    SharedLibrary::clsGPIO^%, 
                                    SharedLibrary::Types^%, 
                                    SharedLibrary::DisplayDriver^%);

        virtual bool DeleteInstance(void);
        virtual void ForceUnload(void);
        virtual void Interrupt(void);
        virtual void Main_Loop(void);
    };
};
```

In my VB.NET Host Application the code is:

```
Class clsInterface    

    <ImportMany(GetType(IPlugin))> _
    Public Plugins As IPlugin()

    Public Sub Load()
        Dim MyDialog As Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog = New FolderBrowserDialog()

        MyDialog.Description = "Bitte Plugin-Verzeichnis auswählen"
        MyDialog.SelectedPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory

        MyDialog.ShowDialog()

        Dim catalog = New DirectoryCatalog(MyDialog.SelectedPath)
        Dim container = New CompositionContainer(catalog)
        container.ComposeParts(Me)
    End Sub

End Class
```

My clsInterface class does not recognize my C++/CLI Plugin even though it's __typeof.

Do you have any Idea? Thank you :)